# Jquery ajax unable to post data

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

Im my Codeigniter view, I have the following code to send the current and new passwords to the controller via jquery ajax function, but it seems like the data is not passed to the controller.
See if you can help me with this.

```
 var url = '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/it_inventory/change_my_pass';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        //datatype: "json",
        data:'cu_pass=' + cu_pass + '&new_pass=' + new_pass,
        success: function(r){
            if(r==1){
                alert("Password Changed Successfully!");
            }else{
                alert("Error changing password!");
            }
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
public function change_my_pass($cu_pass="", $new_pass=""){
    //$cu_pass = $this->input->post('cu_pass');
    //$new_pass = $this->input->post('new_pass');
    echo $this->it_inventory_model->change_my_pass($cu_pass, $new_pass);
}
```

Comment: But where are you even passing data in your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pass post as json data

```
var url = '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/it_inventory/change_my_pass/';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        datatype: "json",
        data:{cu_pass: cu_pass,new_pass: new_pass},
        success: function(r){
            if(r==1){
                alert("Password Changed Successfully!");
            }else{
                alert("Error changing password!");
            }
        }
    });
```

Controller

```
public function change_my_pass($cu_pass="", $new_pass=""){
    $cu_pass = $this->input->post('cu_pass');
    $new_pass = $this->input->post('new_pass');
    echo $this->it_inventory_model->change_my_pass($cu_pass, $new_pass);
}
```

Comment: But that slash at the end of the value of url is not needed!

Answer (score 0):

you can use serialize() method to get the form data and pass it into the ajax data params.

Answer (score 0):

in $.ajax({ url pass only the url of the page 
& remove the variable you want to pass using url 
add in data 
data: {new_pass: new_pass_valu, cu_pass: cu_pass_value},

Answer (score 0):

please check the config of CSRF, if it is open, to bring 'csrf_token_name' param.

**config/config.php**:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cross Site Request Forgery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enables a CSRF cookie token to be set. When set to TRUE, token will be
| checked on a submitted form. If you are accepting user data, it is strongly
| recommended CSRF protection be enabled.
|
| 'csrf_token_name' = The token name
| 'csrf_cookie_name' = The cookie name
| 'csrf_expire' = The number in seconds the token should expire.
*/
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
```

**correct ajax post request:**

```
var url = '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/it_inventory/change_my_pass/';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        //datatype: "json",
        data:'cu_pass=' + cu_pass + '&new_pass=' + new_pass + '&<?php echo config_item('csrf_token_name');?>=<?php echo $this->input->cookie(config_item('csrf_cookie_name'))?>',
        success: function(r){
            if(r==1){
                alert("Password Changed Successfully!");
            }else{
                alert("Error changing password!");
            }
        }
    });
```

**Controller:**

```
public function change_my_pass(){
    $cu_pass = $this->input->post('cu_pass');
    $new_pass = $this->input->post('new_pass');
    echo $this->it_inventory_model->change_my_pass($cu_pass, $new_pass);
}
```